# unable to build xamarin forms 5.0.* locally from sources

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

Due to some custom reasons, we have some custom built-in features in the XF (like the XAML-based toolbar button and changing private-internal to the public classes, plus virtualizing some methods). As the result, we are dependent on the custom version of the XF NuGet package.

It worked (almost always) perfectly until the version XF5.0. I have a dedicated virtual machine with Windows and preinstalled VS for those purposes.

When I'm trying to build XF from sources using the next command
`.\build.ps1 -Target NugetPack -ScriptArgs '--packageVersion="5.0.0.2013"'`
I get the error:

```
Successfully created package 'L:\src_github\xf_patch_release-5.0.0-sr3.1\artifacts\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.WPF.5.0.0.2013.nupkg'.
NuGet Version: 5.9.1.11
Attempting to build package from 'Xamarin.Forms.temp.nuspec'.
Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.<>c.<ValidateReferenceAssemblies>b__173_1(NuGet.Frameworks1204671.NuGetFramework groupFramework)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.ValidateReferenceAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 files, IEnumerable`1 packageAssemblyReferences)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.Save(Stream stream)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage(PackageBuilder builder, String outputPath, Boolean symbolsPackage)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
An error occurred when executing task '_NuGetPack'.
Error: One or more errors occurred. (NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).)
        NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

I've tried to use different methods to get rid of this non-understandable issue, but nothing happened. I've tried to use the latest actual `release-5.0.0-sr3.1` tag and the latest version of the branch `5.0.0`
I've tried to change some settings in the `build.cake` file, to unload some projects from the solution (like UWP-related ones, which usually caused a lot of errors). I've tried to build the solution on my working computer (and environment) - I got the same result.
Then I switched to building the solution in the VS directly and started getting issues like:
[image]

Before calling the main task to build: `.\build.ps1 -Target NugetPack...` I always call the `.\build.ps1 -Target provision` to ensure that I haven't missed some required tools on each Windows OS.

Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that I'm using a different version of the NuGet package manager, which I had to install globally on my OS. The right version can be found in the XF's Pipelines (https://dev.azure.com/xamarin/public/_build, see the Windows-related builds).
After I've changed the global version to 5.6.0, the build script started generating the *.nupkg file for the Xamarin.Forms project itself correctly.

...